# How to "PUT" json data contains Chinese characters?

Tags: python-3.x, put

I want to use python's http library to send a PUT request to the server, the json data contains Chinese characters.

I used requests, urllib， but the updated data in the database is unicode, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Unicode contains chinese characters. Where's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it.

Before code:

```py
data = {'k1': v1, 'k2': v2}
r = requests.put(url, json=data, headers=headers)
```

After:

```py
data = {'k1': v1, 'k2': v2}
data_json = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False).encode()
r = requests.put(url, data=data_json, headers=headers)
```

btw，Can someone explain why? Very grateful